# import he5 files into R

Tags: r, hdf

I want to import he5 irradiance files from giovanni. See a list [here](http://giovanni.gsfc.nasa.gov/giovanni/#service=ZnMn&starttime=&endtime=&dataKeyword=Irradiance).
This [post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/142630/hdf-eos5-file-format-import-in-grass) shows how to import he5 files into QGIS, but I'd like to import them into R. Is it possible? I tried package `rhdf5` but couldn't find how to do it.

Comment: what have you tried, and what didn't work for you, please edit your answer using the [edit](http://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/219225/edit) link, to include this sort of information. I tried your example link, but it needs some sort of authentication, so that's not particularly useful, can you suplly a link to another sample

Comment: I wrote a link to the list of irradiance files now. Must register to download them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use two packages, `raster` and `ncdf4`. The first one will let you  open raster file; the second one, to assign `ncdf4` space into raster package and view metadata. **Important**: is necessary to select *Data field*, you can't open all *Data field* at the same time (or at less I don't know how to do it without a `for` or `do.call` function). An example with the file that you give us:

```
library(raster)
library(ncdf4)

# View Data fields
nc_open("/path/to/OMI-Aura_L3-OMUVBd_2004m1001_v003-2016m0525t164359.he5")

File /path/to/OMI-Aura_L3-OMUVBd_2004m1001_v003-2016m0525t164359.he5 (NC_FORMAT_NETCDF4):

     19 variables (excluding dimension variables):
        float Data Fields/CSErythemalDailyDose[Data Fields/phony_dim_1,Data Fields/phony_dim_0]   (Chunking: [90,23])  (Compression: level 5)
            MissingValue: -1.26765060022823e+30
            Offset: 0
            ScaleFactor: 1
            _FillValue: -1.26765060022823e+30
            Title: Clear Sky Erythemal Daily Dose
            UniqueFieldDefinition: OMI-Specific
            Units: J/m2
.
.
.

# Open Data field as raster
r <- raster("/path/to/OMI-Aura_L3-OMUVBd_2004m1001_v003-2016m0525t164359.he5",
            var="Data Fields/CSIrradiance324",ncdf=TRUE)

plot(r)
```

[image: rplot]